# Redirect to Homepage when password changed

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, redirect, ajaxform

I am working with some php and I need the page to redirect if the password has been changed successfully. Presently it changes the password when I click submit but nothing happens. I am kind of stuck on this, this is my first time working with `PHP` so any help would be appreciated please. Below is my model code.

```
public function change_password($user_id, $hash)
{
    $query = "UPDATE users SET password=? WHERE user_id=?";

    if($this->db->query($query, array($hash, $user_id))){

        return TRUE;

    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
     public function security_settings(){
    $pass = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);
    $cpass = $this->input->post('cpassword', TRUE);
    $user_id = $this->user->user_id;

    if($pass==='' || $cpass==='')
    {
        echo '{"msg":"alert alert-danger","html":"Passwords do not match"}';
        return;
    }

    if($pass!=$cpass)
    {
        echo '{"msg":"alert alert-danger","html":"Passwords do not match"}';
        return;
    }

    $hash = $this->phpass->hash($pass);
    while(strlen($hash) < 20){
        $hash = $this->phpass->hash($pass);
    }

    if($this->profile_model->change_password($user_id, $hash))
    {
        echo '{"msg":"alert alert-info","html":"Changes have been saved successfully"}';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '{"msg":"alert alert-danger","html":"<b>Error!</b> Unable to save changes"}';
    }
}
```

and this is the view:

```
    <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="defform" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('profile/security_settings') ?>">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="password">New Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter new password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm new password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes

                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

here is the javascript code i used for ajax form submission:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    $('#defform').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        fields: {
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                        max: 50,
                        message: 'The password must be more between 8 to 50 characters long'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password2',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            cpassword: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The confirm password is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                        max: 50,
                        message: 'The password must be more between 8 to 50 characters long'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


    $('#defform').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
                    $('#info-well').removeClass().addClass(response.msg);
                    $('#info-well').html(response.html);
                 }
    });


});
```

Comment: Looks like you're using AJAX, could you post the js code?

Comment: You are using ajax to submit form, right?

Comment: @DamienPirsy I am posting the js code now.

Comment: @ArslanAfzal Yes i am, i just added a snippet of my javascript.

Comment: You can use jquery Location() to redirect the Current page with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to `msg` and `html` add 2 more values for `redirected` and `page`
an example can be like

```
'{"msg":".....","html":".....","redirect":1,"page":base_url()."/controller"} // if you want a redirect.
```

and

```
'{"msg":".....","html":".....","redirect":0,"page":"#"} // if you do not want a redirect.
```

in js you will have

```
    $('#defform').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                        $('#info-well').removeClass().addClass(response.msg);
                        $('#info-well').html(response.html);
                         //you can set a timeout here of say 5 seconds so that user can read the success message and append text like redirecting to.....
                         if(response.redirected==1) {window.location.href = response.page;} //this line will redirect to the controller.

                     }
        });
```